# How to create a program that will store 50 random numbers in a list, and find average?

Tags: python, python-2.3

How would I:

> Write a function that will take a single parameter of an integer, and return a list of that many random numbers between 1 and 100.
>
> Using this function, write a program that will store 50 random numbers in a list, and then calculate and print out the average of all the numbers.

Comment: Please read [ask] - you are expected to show your own attempt.

Comment: import random
number =int(input("Please enter a number"))
def myfunction(number):
    output = []
    return output[random.randint(number)]

for x in range(1):

Comment: Edit your question to include properly formatted code. Are you really using Python-2.3? I just you upgrade to a later version

Answer (score 0):

Below a solution using numpy array :

```
import numpy as np

def randomx(nb):
    random_array = np.random.randint(1, 100, nb)
    print mean(random_array)
```